# Is this function an injection of $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, irrational-numbers, pi, arithmetic-functions

This comes from an [earlier question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520013/592365). It seems unapproachable.

> Is the arithmetic function
>   $$f(n) := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1{\sin(k)}$$
>   An injection?

I *think* the answer is yes.

Comment: I feel sort of Fourier will be useful here but I don't have any ideas off the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is an injection - this may be solved by observing that
$$\sin(k)=\frac{z^k-z^{-k}}{2i}$$
where $z=e^i$. The importance of this transformation is that $z$ is transcendental, hence two rational functions of $z$ with rational (or, generally, algebraic) coefficients are equal if and only if they are equal as rational functions. If we toss out the coefficient of $2i$, since its a constant multiplied by every term, we then find that the question asks whether the sums
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{z^k-z^{-k}}$$
are all distinct at $z=e^i$. This is then equivalent to asking whether these summands are equal *everywhere* as functions of $z$ since "transcendental" means that any polynomial or rational equation with rational coefficients that is true for $z$ is true for *every* number - but clearly no pair of these functions are equal everywhere because the $n^{th}$ term has a pole at every ${2n}^{th}$ root of unity, whereas no prior function has this property.